# Error: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting the following error when I try to validate my XML against my XSD:

> [Error] try.xsd:20:46: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence'
>   must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence |
>   any)*). A problem was found starting at: complexType.

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfAccountParameterInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AccountParameterInfo>
    <Name>System Name</Name>
    <Identifier>1</Identifier>
    <Type>8</Type>
    <Length>20</Length>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <MinValue />
    <MaxValue />
    <Default />
    <CodePage>1252</CodePage>
    <Section>-1</Section>
    <Tab>-1</Tab>
    <Row>-1</Row>
    <Column>-1</Column>
  </AccountParameterInfo>    
  <AccountParameterInfo>
    <Name>Siren Arming Indication</Name>
    <Identifier>2</Identifier>
    <Type>7</Type>
    <Length>1</Length>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <MinValue />
    <MaxValue />
    <Default />
    <CodePage>1252</CodePage>
    <SelectorList>
      <string>None</string>
      <string>AllCases</string>
      <string>KeyAndKeyfob</string>
    </SelectorList>
    <Section>-1</Section>
    <Tab>-1</Tab>
    <Row>-1</Row>
    <Column>-1</Column>
  </AccountParameterInfo>
 </ArrayOfAccountParameterInfo>
```

The schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsi:element name="ArrayOfAccountParameterInfo">
    <xsi:complexType>
        <xsi:sequence>
            <xsi:element name="AccountParameterInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsi:complexType>
                    <xsi:sequence>
                        <xsi:element name="Name" type="xsi:string"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Identifier" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Type" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Length" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Order" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="MinValue" type="xsi:string"/>
                        <xsi:element name="MaxValue" type="xsi:string"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Default" type="xsi:string"/>
                        <xsi:element name="CodePage" type="xsi:string"/>
                        <xsi:element name="SelectorList" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xsi:complexType>
                                <xsi:sequence>
                                    <xsi:element name="string" type="xsi:string"/> 
                                </xsi:sequence>
                            </xsi:complexType>
                        <xsi:element name="Section" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Tab" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Row" type="xsi:integer"/>
                        <xsi:element name="Column" type="xsi:integer"/>
                    </xsi:sequence>
                </xsi:complexType>
            </xsi:element>
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>
</xsi:element>
</xsi:schema>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your XSD is malformed.  The declaration for `SelectorList`, despite indentation, is wrong:

```
                    <xsi:element name="SelectorList" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsi:complexType>
```

should be

```
                    <xsi:element name="SelectorList" minOccurs="0">
                        <xsi:complexType>
```

`string` should also be allowed to repeat (`maxOccurs="unbounded"`).

**Note also:** You shouldn't use `xsi` for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.  By convention, use `xs` or `xsd` instead; `xsi` is typically used for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Here is  your corrected XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfAccountParameterInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AccountParameterInfo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Order" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="MinValue" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="MaxValue" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Default" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="CodePage" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="SelectorList" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="string" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                type="xs:string"/> 
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Section" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Tab" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Row" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Column" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It will validate your XML successfully.

Comment: Much appreciation for your quick and elaborate answer. I've tried it all over.

Comment: You're welcome.  Does *I've tried it all over* mean that your problem is solved?  If so, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer.  If not, please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant that I've tried your solution several times before but obviously had one error (the slash). Yes it validated perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: (And just to be clear, there were *two* errors and one flagrant violation of conventions pointed out in my answer.)